# Does Jsch support third party scp file transfer operation?

Tags: ssh, scp, jsch

I need to copy files between two remote machines(let's say A and B) using SCP. Let's say my java code running on machine C and i need to move a file from A to B, what i currently do is SCP file from A to C and then do an another SCP from C to B. But I got to know that SCP support transferring file between two remote hosts directly using "SCP -3 " option. I uses jsch library to do scp between two machines. Does jsch support above operation? if not any other library i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsch doesn't contain any direct support for the SCP protocol. You could use jsch to make connections to the remote servers and interact with them, but you'd have to implement your own SCP logic on top of that.

You can find a description of the SCP protocol [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works). For your use case, you'd do something like this:

1. Open a Jsch session to the source host.
2. Open an exec channel on the source host, invoking scp to send the source file(s).
3. Open a jsch session to the target host.
4. Open an exec channel on the target host, invoking scp to receive the file(s).
5. Read file data from the source channel and write it to the target channel.

Having said that, Jsch *does* support SFTP, and SFTP is generally a superior protocol to SCP. You should consider using SFTP to do this instead of SCP.